# VS Code 32 bit in Windows 11 64 bit replacement

Tags: 64-bit

I just got a notice in my VS Code that the 32 bit version was not going to be supported much longer and it was recommended to upgrade to the 64 bit version. Can I just install the 64 bit version over the 32 bit version? I am concerned about losing the extensions and settings.
Or can I uninstall the 32 bit version, install the 64 bit version, and depend on settings synce to fix?

Comment: I haven't written any extensions, but if they are compiled as 32-bit instead of being source or size-neutral bytecode  you might need to get the 64-bit versions.  You could try using a VirtualBox or Hyper-V VM for the 64-bit version to test things before upgrading.  FYI you can install Windows 10 in a VM and skip activation so no license is needed.